# Rails - Why does my nested model form not require 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models `item` and `user_item`.  `Item` has many `user_items` and `user_items` belongs to `item`.  I have a form where a user can create a new item.  In the form a user should include a picture.  The name, description, and tags get saved to a new item object.  The picture should be saved as an attribute on a user_item object which gets created at the same time.

I've been reading about nested model forms and strong parameters and using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  My form seems to be working but I don't understand why I don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  Although it seems to be working, is there a problem with the way I'm doing it?

**Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @item, url: items_path, method: :post do |item_builder| %>
  <div class="well">
  <%= item_builder.input :name, required: false, error: false, label: "Item name" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :description, as: :text, required: false, error: false, label: "Describe item" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :tag_list, required: false, label: "Tags" %>
  <%= item_builder.simple_fields_for @item, @item.user_items.build do |user_item_builder| %>
    <%= user_item_builder.input :picture, as: :file, required: false, label: "Picture of you with this item" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= item_builder.submit 'Submit new item', class: "btn btn-primary pull-right inherit-width" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Items_controller**

```
def create
    Item.transaction do

      @item = Item.create(name: item_params[:name],
                                        description: item_params[:description],
                                        tag_list: item_params[:tag_list], 
                                        created_by: current_user.id,
                                        status: Item::STATUS[:pending])

      if item_params[:item] == nil
        @item.errors.add(:picture, "is required")
      end

      if @item.errors.empty?
        @user_item = @item.user_items.build(user_id: current_user.id, picture: item_params[:item][:picture])

        if @user_item.save
          flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your item submission."
          redirect_to items_path
        else
          render :new
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Useritem create failed"
        end

      else
        render :new
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "no picture"
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :tag_list,
                                                                item: :picture)
    end
```

EDIT:

I have made changes going along with Richard's answer below but I am now running into a couple problems.  This is my current create action in the items_controller

```
  def create
    @item= Item.new item_params
    @item.status = Item::STATUS[:pending]
    @item.created_by = current_user.id
    @item.user_items.first.user_id = current_user.id
    if @item.save
      redirect_to items_path, notice: "Thank you for your item request!
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

1. On validation fail I was getting a missing template error so I added an `else` and `render :new`.
2. Now on validation fail the new template is rendered but the fields_for input for picture is not shown.
3. I have `validates_presence_of :picture` in user_item.rb and I have
   `validates_associated :user_items` in item.rb but I am still able to submit the form without a picture.
4. As you can see on valid submission I need the item's status attribute to be pending and a created_by attribute to be the current user id.  I also needed the user_item's user_id attribute to be set to the current user id.  I set this in the controller.  I am wondering if setting this like I am in the create action is the correct way.

Comment: Its kind of hard to figure out what you are doing since here. You have a strong parameters method but your not using it. `simple_fields_for @item, @item.user_items.build` is just strange - just pass it the name of the association you want to create fields for. Also for read the guide for whitelisting nested params:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need it because your pattern is wrong:

```
@user_item = @item.user_items.build(user_id: current_user.id, picture: item_params[:item][:picture])
```

With your above code, you're creating individual `user_items` from each `@item`. This does not require [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), but is cumbersome, against [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) and very hacky.

---

Here's how it should be done:

**Models**

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_items
  has_many :users, through: :user_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_items
end

#app/models/user_item.rb
class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

**Controllers**

```
#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @item.user_items.build
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new item_params
    redirect_to @item, notice: "Thank you for your item submission." if @item.save
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :tag_list, user_items_attributes: [:picture])
  end
end
```

**Views**

```
#app/views/items/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @item do |item_builder| %>
  <%= item_builder.input :name, required: false, error: false, label: "Item name" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :description, as: :text, required: false, error: false, label: "Describe item" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :tag_list, required: false, label: "Tags" %>
  <%= item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_items do |user_item_builder| %>
    <%= user_item_builder.input :picture, as: :file, required: false, label: "Picture of you with this item" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= item_builder.submit 'Submit new item', class: "btn btn-primary pull-right inherit-width" %>
<% end %>
```

---

> is there a problem with the way I'm doing it

Technically, *no*.

However, if you aspire to be a professional, or on a similar level, you'll not get very far with the code you wrote.

Using a framework like Rails gives you access to an unprecedented array of pre-baked functionality. The best code is not the code you wrote, but the library code that's been compiled & tested over years of production use.

Whilst your code works, it's not efficient nor [extensible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design#Design_Concepts).

--

The ultimate key of whether what you've written is "right" is whether the future you would be proud of looking at it again. If not, you're probably best refactoring.

---

**Update**

If you want to give `Item` a `status`, you'll want to look at the [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) module for ActiveRecord models:

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:active, :pending, :declined]
end
```

This is a very interesting method, as it provides a series of class methods (scopes), and instance methods:

```
@item = Item.find x

@item.active?   #-> true
@item.pending?  #-> false
@item.declined? #-> false

Item.active     #-> collection of "active" items
Item.pending    #-> collection of "pending" items
Item.declined   #-> collection of "declined" items
```

To save an Item's `status`, you could use the `collection_select` as so:

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :status, Item.statuses, :first, :first %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

Your code can be improved massively:

```
def create
    @item= Item.new item_params #-> this line should do ALL the heavy lifting.

    if @item.save
      redirect_to items_path, notice: "Thank you for your item request!"
    else
      render :new
    end
end

private

def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :tag_list, user_items_attributes: [:picture]).merge(created_by: current_user.id)
end
```

The `file` field won't be populated again if you have validation issues; it's an OS problem, not Rails (how does the OS know your file is in the same location as it was when you first submitted?).

You need to make your `create` code as succinct as possible; explicit declarations for attributes is generally a bad idea. You should put as much of it as possible into the `Item` model (`enum` etc).

Comment: Good answer. Although from the OP UserItem is just 1-1 and not a join table or he just has not thought though the domain enough. This makes `has_many :items, through: :user_items` kind of strange as it would make the model self joining.

Comment: This "proud" thing never works for me. From which I must conclude that I am not a professional. :)

Comment: I didn't mean to insinuate disrespect; the guy was asking about whether his code was legit which - in the context of rails - it isn't. He obviously wants to improve so I *meant* that if he took it to an employer, it wouldn't be held in as high regard as someone who'd experienced the framework enough to know the intricacies etc. Kind of like turning up to an interview in shorts

Comment: No worries, I was joking :)

Comment: Why is the line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :item` in the user_item model?  I thought this would only be needed in the item model.

Comment: In my item model I have a status attribute.  Code in my item.rb looks like `STATUS = { pending: 0, active: 1, declined: 2 } 

  scope :active, -> { where(status: Item::STATUS[:active]) }
  scope :approved, -> { where(status: Item::STATUS[:active]).where.not(created_by: nil) }
  scope :pending, -> { where(status: Item::STATUS[:pending]) }
  scope :declined, -> { where(status: Item::STATUS[:declined]) }`  How would you set the status of the item in the create method?

Comment: Why is the line accepts_nested_attributes_for :item in the user_item model? I thought this would only be needed in the item model. -- you're totally right; I was thinking you needed to extend the functionaity (edited)

Comment: You'd be best using an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), I'll write an update

Comment: Where can I set the user_id attribute to `current_user` on the user_item that is created with the form submission?  I also need to set a "created_by" attribute to the current_user on the item that is created.  Would I do this in the controller in the create action after setting @badge?

Comment: What's `@badge`? The `created_by` attribute is set automatically. If you set `current_user.user_items.new`, it automatically sets `user_id` for it. If not ,you can use `.merge(user_id: current_user.id)` in the params

Comment: Are you online tomorrow? I have to go sleep right now (long day); will be online tomorrow

Comment: Yes I will be.  Please see my edit above.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I saw your recent update and it helped with setting `created_by`.  I still have a couple issues.  When validation fails its not that the file field isn't populated on render, the entire field is not there at all.  Also I need the user_id to be set for when the user_item is created.  And picture validation isn't working.  I could join a chat if you'd like or make a new question with these issues - whichever is easiser for you.  Very thankful for your help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! A new question would be the best solution - I am online now, if you post the link here I can comment for you

Comment: Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319988/rails-validating-complex-nested-form thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Although it seems to be working, is there a problem with the way I'm
>   doing it?

Its great that it works - however it does have a *code smell*. Your controller has way to much business logic which belongs on the model layer and you would be forced to repeat that whole mess with the param checking in your update action.

So lets look at *the Rails way*:

```
class Item
  enum status: [:pending, :approved, :awesome] # or whatever statuses you have
  has_many :user_items
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User' # or author or whatever
  validates_associated :user_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_items, reject_if: :all_blank?
end

class UserItem
  belongs_to :item
  validates :picture, presence: true
end

class User
  has_many :items, source: :creator, inverse_of: :creator
end
```

Here we setup item to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_items` and we setup a validations for UserItem, `validates_associated` will cause the Item validation to fail unless all the associated UserItems are valid.

[ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) is a less hacky way of doing what I believe you are doing with `item.status`.

With our models taken care of we can proceed to with the controller:

```
class ItemsController

  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @item.user_items.new # seeds the form
  end

  def edit
    @item.user_items.new unless @item.user_items.any? # seeds the form
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params) do |item|
      item.status = :pending
      item.creator = current_user
    end
    if @item.save
      redirect_to items_path, success: 'Oh yes'
    else
      render :new, error: 'Oh noes'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      redirect_to @item, success: 'Item updated'
    else
      render :edit, error: 'Oh noes'
    end
  end

  private 
    def set_item
      @item = Item.includes(:user_items).find(params[:id])
    end

    def item_params
      params.require(:item)
            .permit(:name, :description, :tag_list, user_items_attributes: [:picture])
    end
end
```

This is MVC *the Rails way* - models take care of validations and associations. We use strong parameters to map form input to models in a reusable way.

Lastly lets clean up the form. We will start by extracting the form into a partial so that it can be re-used.

```
<% # views/items/_form.html.erb %>
<%= simple_form_for @item do |item_builder| %>
  <div class="well">
    <%= item_builder.input :name, require: false, label: "Item name" %>
    <%= item_builder.input :description, require: false, as: :text, label: "Describe item" %>
    <%= item_builder.input :tag_list, label: "Tags", require: false %>
    <%= item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_items do |user_item_builder| %>
    <%= user_item_builder.input :picture, as: :file, label: "Picture of you with this item" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= item_builder.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

We can then use this form for both `new` and `edit`.

```
<h1>Create a new item</h1>
<%= render partial: '_form' %>
```

---

```
<h1>Edit <%= @item.name %></h1>
<%= render partial: '_form' %>
```

Comment: Note that you need to rethink a bit if you want **other users** then the user that has created the item to be able to submit pictures of themselves with an Item. That would require different relations, routes and controllers.